# How To Combine Multiple Strings Contained in 1 variable into 1 String

Tags: python, json, string

Im taking a really complex way to do this and am really confused but here I go!

Ok so I basically took the result like a normal dict which is `result = j_result['result']` j_result is the variable containing all of the information in the following image.

and then with that im skipping title and simply extracting everything inside the result with this script

```
def extract_values(obj, key):
            arr = []
            def extract(obj, arr, key):
                if isinstance(obj, dict):
                    for k, v in obj.items():
                        if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                            extract(v, arr, key)
                        elif k == key:
                            arr.append(v)
                elif isinstance(obj, list):
                    for item in obj:
                        extract(item, arr, key)
                return arr

            results = extract(obj, arr, key)
            return results
        def listToString(s):
```

And with that value im replacing all of the weird characters such as [, ], ', etc. when I finally have a good string that parsed everything im left with the pretty string, but the majority of them contain a character | seperating the japanese and english names, I used this script to remove everything before that leaving english

```
o_string = oe_string.replace(",", "\n")  
for l in o_string.split('\n'):
   thingy1 = l.split('|')[-1] + "\n"
   print(repr(thingy1))
```

But when I do this it print multiple strings represented through `thingy1`

example: output coming from the print function in the above script

```
'string 1'
'string 2'
'string 3'
```

I want to combine all of the of these strings into 1 string, and seperate new lines with \n.

So in gist instead of having 3 lines I want something that looks like this:

```
string 1\nstring 2\nstring 3\n
```

and so on...

Sorry if this isnt the right way to phraze this etc, or for this purpose. But im really at a lost and anything helps.

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/696842088431485069/701708282162708480/unknown.png?width=720&height=42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a list of strings and want to combine them into a single string with a separator (`\n`) in between them?

That's what `.join` is for!

```
l = ['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']
joined = '\n'.join(l)
# now joined is 'string 1\nstring 2\nstring 3'
```